# is it okay to use the default collation (latin_swedish_ci)?

Tags: mysql, collation

I searched some opinions that only states that they converting from `latin` to `utf8`, may I ask if I can use `latin_swedish_ci`? It has no difference from english chars so, is it okay? Additionally, if I have a `meta-charset` of `UTF-8` on my web app and I'm using `latin_swedish_ci collation`, does it affect or something ? I want your opinions about this.

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend you to use `utf8mb4` instead of `latin_swedish_ci` or even  `utf8`.

Even `latin_swedish_ci` supports all English letters, it can and will eventually kick you in your ass. For example names, addresses and much more stuff can contain other characters and that can mess up your stored data or even worse can produce plain errors!

So why not just `utf8` you'll ask? Because in MySQL `utf8` uses 3 bytes to store a character and cannot store every utf-8 character, you need 4 bytes for this and therefore you need `utf8mb4`. This can bite you in the ass if you have to deal with user entries and mobile users decide to put in some fancy emoticons as entries. Happened to me some times.

Don't ask me why MySQL messed up the whole Unicode thing in this way, I don't know... Maybe the same reason why `latin_swedish_ci` is the default.

In general, use full Unicode for everything text related and you are safe. The Web is huge and international and storage to keep some extra bytes is cheap enough. Just get used to it now even if you don't really need it and you will be prepared for the future.

Answer (score 3):

A `CHARACTER SET` refers to the way characters are encoded.  A `COLLATION` refers to the way characters are compared (for equality or for ordering).  For each character set, there is a list of possible collations.  (Spanish and German have some notable variations.)

Both character sets `latin1` and `utf8` encode English text identically.  So, if you are using only English, then the `CHARACTER SET` does not matter.  Even the default collations for those two character sets will act the same for English.

If you get into other languages, or even emoticons, the the questions raised become important.

It is often OK for the application client and MySQL server to be using different character sets.  The conversion will happen automatically.  *But*, you must tell MySQL what character set the application bytes are using.  (Again, for English, this is not critical.)  That is done in a variety of ways, depending on the client (Java, PHP, VB, Python, etc, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate for mentioning that Both character sets latin1 and utf8 encode English text identically. This sounds true !